# Translating German Birth Register (1861)

Tags: birth-records, prussia

I found a set of birth records for some ancestors of mine in the Polish archives (FamilySearch film #8004076). They are from [New Waltersdorf](https://www.meyersgaz.org/place/20304055), in southern part of Silesia.  I have two scans, from facing pages in the record book, and I am struggling with deciphering the handwriting.  (Not speaking German doesn't help, I am sure)

This appears to be a birth record for Anselma Lauterbach, daughter of Heinrich and Anselma (Rasch) Lauterbach, born on 23-Feb-1861 (the record was in the section of the register for 1861). The last column on the right page has a cross and the date 16/11 64, which I have interpreted to mean that she died on that day.

I am especially interested in the parents, grandparents and godparents of the child.

[image: Left Hand page]
[image: Right hand page]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

transcript ....translation

image 1
**Headings**
Tag, Stunde der Geburt ................Day and hour of birth
Namen und Stand der Eltern .........Names and standing (occupation, class) of parents
Geschlecht und Namen der Kinder ......Gender and name of children
Wer getauft hat ..........Who performed the baptism
Tag der Taufe ..............Date of the baptism

**Entry**
d.  23t. Februar, Nachmittag um 3 Uhr .....the 23d of February, after noon about 3 o'clock
Heinrich Lauterbach Hslr. [Häusler] u. Schneider von hier. Anselma geb. Rasch aus Conradswalde |: geboren zu Camenz :| ....Henry Lauterbach, cottager? and tailor resident here. Anselma nee Rasch from Conradswalde (born in Camenz)
eheliche Tochter Anselma ...legitimate daughter Anselma
Pfarrer Roensdr. ...Pastor Roensdr. [abbreviation?]
d. 27t Februar ...the 27th of February

**note below entry**
Vät. [Väterliche] Großeltern ...paternal grandparents
illigitim. Barbara Lauterbach von hier ...illegitimate [ie no father]. Barbara Lauterbach from here
Mütterliche " [Großeltern ] ...maternal grandparents
Heinrich Rasch, Bildhauer zu Conradswalde, Elisabeth geb Galle aus Schwarzwasser .....Henry Rasch sculptor in Conradswalde, Elizabeth nee Galle from Schwarzwasser

image 2
**Headings**
der Taufpathe ...godparent
die Zeugen ...the Witnesses
Nummer der Tauflinge ...[sequential] number of those baptized
Männlich, ehelich, unehel. ...male, legitimate, illegitimate
Weiblich,  ehelich, unehel. ...female, legitimate, illegitimate
Bemerkungen ....Comments
Transport ...Carryover [totals from previous page]

**Entry**
Adelheid des Franz Petsch bürgerlichen Hutmachers Ehewirthin aus Landeck. ...Adelheid, from Landeck, wife? of Frans Petsch, burgher (citizen and) hatmaker
Junggesell Joseph, des Ignatz Dittert Häusler u. Schuhmachers ehelicher Sohn von hier, dann Junggesell Julius des Franz Zoche Gastwirths ehelicher Sohn von hier u. Jungesell Joseph, des + Joseph Rücker gewesenen Bauers ehelich hinterlassener Sohn von hier. .....Bachelor Joseph, legitimate son of Ignatz Dittert cottager and shoemaker, from here, also bachelor Julius legitimate son of Franz Zoche, tavernkeeper, from here, and bachelor Joseph, legitimate son of deceased Joseph Rücker, former farmer, from here.
12 . . 1 . .........#12, 1 legitimate female
+16/11 64 ......died 16 Nov [18]64

Abbreviations are expanded between [], also some notes
A few English words are marked ? - may need alternative translations.

Comment: Context: Adelheid (Rasch) Petch was the sister of Anselma (Rasch) Lauterbach

Comment: And thanks!!!!!